# Does the app speed or SQL speed depend on my Django choice field string length?

Tags: python, sql, performance, django-models

I would like to know if it is still important these days to keep the strings you use in SQL "Where" queries as short as possible.

I have two different Choice tables here.

```
staff_intern_role = [
    ("HP", "Head of Postproduction"),
    ("HS", "Head of Sales"),
    ("PS", "Postproduction Supervisor"),
    ("TD", "Technical Director"),
    ("CL", "Colorist"),
    ("RM", "Re-Recording Mixer"),
    ("OE", "Online Editing"),
    ("VE", "VFX Editing"),
    ("DM", "DCP Mastering"),
]

staff_intern_role = [
    ("Head of Postproduction", "Head of Postproduction"),
    ("Head of Sales", "Head of Sales"),
    ("Postproduction Supervisor", "Postproduction Supervisor"),
    ("Technical Director", "Technical Director"),
    ("Colorist", "Colorist"),
    ("Re-Recording Mixer", "Re-Recording Mixer"),
    ("Online Editing", "Online Editing"),
    ("VFX Editing", "VFX Editing"),
    ("DCP Mastering", "DCP Mastering"),
]
```

Personally, I would like to take the last one that is easy to read.  So far I haven't found any information about this. Of course shorter strings are also compared faster. That is already clear to me. But does that really still matter with today's hardware ? I would like to keep the code well readable and would find it good if one can also look at the tables with a SQL editor and read and understand the contents well:.

My app scenario is a database with about 20 tables and a maximum of 10,000 rows.
So it's not about optimizing millions of entries.

Comment: Tables with dependent columns break the [third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). For your first table, if you meant to create a lookup table, I would use an INT surrogate key (also breaks 3NF, but only 1 INT wide). As for your second table, why would you store twice the same text ?

Comment: I use the Django framework. Within my models I can define choice lists. These are two examples. The first column is stored as database value and the second column is the output in the output templates. I would like to know if I should rather use the first variant or second variant as choice. In other words, can I store lane strings in a SQL table or should I rather use short aliases?

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding these are python side definitions, not SQL tables. My point still stand though, if this is an enum, then consider it as such and use a simple surrogate key like and INT. However, the difference between an INT, a CHAR(2) and a VARCHAR should have very little effect on 10k records.